# Cakephp Form helper PostLink edit

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.

Is it possible to use the form helper postLink function to update a record? Basically I want a  "Approve" button that changes the "Approved" field of a record to 1.

Everything I can find only relates to performing a delete function? The docs don't go into much details either.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance

My code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Approve'), array(
                                     'controller' => 'expenseclaims',
                                     'action' => 'edit', $expenseClaim['ExpenseClaim']['id'],
                                     'approved' => '1',                                                     
                                     'approved_by' => $adminUser,
                                 ), array(
                                     'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
                                 ), __('Are you sure you want to Approve # %s?',$expenseClaim['ExpenseClaim']['id']
                                )); ?>
```

New code: view post link:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Approve'), array('action' => 'approve', $expenseClaim['ExpenseClaim']['id'], 'admin' => true), array('class' => 'btn btn-danger'), __('Are you sure you want to Approve # %s?',$expenseClaim['ExpenseClaim']['id']));
                                ?>
```

Controller code:

```
public function admin_approve($id = null) {

    debug($this->request);

    $this->ExpenseClaim->id = $id;
    if (!$this->request->is('post') && !$this->request->is('put')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    if (!$this->ExpenseClaim->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid expense claim'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        $this->request->data['ExpenseClaim']['approved'] = '1';
        $this->request->data['ExpenseClaim']['approved_by'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if ($this->ExpenseClaim->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The expense claim has been Approved', 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The expense claim could not be approved. Please, try again.', 'flash_failure');
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, of course that is possible.

just post to something like

```
/expenseclaims/approve/id
```

to trigger the `approve` action for example:

```
public function approve($id = null) { 
    if (!$this->request->is('post') && !$this->request->is('put')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    //validate/save
}
```

you can also make it more generic, of course

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my answer with my code, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm guessing I shouldn't use edit and I should write a separate approve function?

Comment: well, you could probably post it directly to edit as well, if you make `edit` generic enough

Comment: Mark, sorry, not sure if your still around, but struggling getting this to work - I've updated my question with the new code, could you take a look? Massive thanks.

Comment: the second check is not necessary (`if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) `). you also need to set the id `$this->request->data['ExpenseClaim']['id'] = $id`